# Generalizing *sql.Rows Scan in Go

Tags: sql, go, reflection, refactoring, generalization

I am developing a web API using Go and there is a lot of redundant database query scan code.

```
func (m *ContractModel) WorkQuestions(cid int) ([]models.WorkQuestion, error) {
    results, err := m.DB.Query(queries.WORK_QUESTIONS, cid)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var workQuestions []models.WorkQuestion
    for results.Next() {
        var wq models.WorkQuestion
        err = results.Scan(&wq.ContractStateID, &wq.QuestionID, &wq.Question, &wq.ID, &wq.Answer, &wq.Compulsory)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        workQuestions = append(workQuestions, wq)
    }

    return workQuestions, nil
}

func (m *ContractModel) Questions(cid int) ([]models.Question, error) {
    results, err := m.DB.Query(queries.QUESTIONS, cid)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var questions []models.Question
    for results.Next() {
        var q models.Question
        err = results.Scan(&q.Question, &q.Answer)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        questions = append(questions, q)
    }

    return questions, nil
}

func (m *ContractModel) Documents(cid int) ([]models.Document, error) {
    results, err := m.DB.Query(queries.DOCUMENTS, cid)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var documents []models.Document
    for results.Next() {
        var d models.Document
        err = results.Scan(&d.Document, &d.S3Region, &d.S3Bucket, &d.Source)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        documents = append(documents, d)
    }

    return documents, nil
}
```

I need to generalize this code so that I can pass in the result `*sql.Rows` to a function and obtain a struct slice containing the scanned rows. I know that there is a `StructScan` method in **sqlx** package but this cannot be used since I have a significant amount of code written using the go standard **database/sql** package.

Using the reflect package, I can create a generic StructScan function but reflect package cannot create a slice of struct from a passed interface{} type. What I need to achieve is something like as follows

```
func RowsToStructs(rows *sql.Rows, model interface{}) ([]interface{}, error) {
    // 1. Create a slice of structs from the passed struct type of model
    // 2. Loop through each row,
    // 3. Create a struct of passed mode interface{} type
    // 4. Scan the row results to a slice of interface{}
    // 5. Set the field values of struct created in step 3 using the slice in step 4
    // 6. Add the struct created in step 3 to slice created in step 1
    // 7. Return the struct slice
}
```

I cannot seem to find a way to scan the struct passed as the model parameter and create a slice of it using the reflect package. Is there any workaround to this or am I looking at the question in a wrong way?

*Struct fields has the correct number of cols returned from the result and in correct order*

Comment: What is the association between columns in the result set and the struct fields?

Comment: Struct fields has the correct number of cols returned from the result and in correct order

Comment: `sqlx` works with the standard `database/sql` package. And if you have to re-write your code anyway, to accomodate your new abstraction, why not just use `sqlx`, instead of re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: @Flimzy sqlx implements part of what I'm trying to achieve not the complete implementation

Comment: @S.Sandeep: Which part does sqlx not do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can avoid using a type assertion in the calling function by passing a pointer to the destination slice as an argument.  Here's RowsToStructs with that modification:

```
// RowsToStructs scans rows to the slice pointed to by dest.
// The slice elements must be pointers to structs with exported
// fields corresponding to the the columns in the result set.
//
// The function panics if dest is not as described above.
func RowsToStructs(rows *sql.Rows, dest interface{}) error {

    // 1. Create a slice of structs from the passed struct type of model
    //
    // Not needed, the caller passes pointer to destination slice.
    // Elem() dereferences the pointer.
    //
    // If you do need to create the slice in this function
    // instead of using the argument, then use
    // destv := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.TypeOf(model).

    destv := reflect.ValueOf(dest).Elem()

    // Allocate argument slice once before the loop.

    args := make([]interface{}, destv.Type().Elem().NumField())

    // 2. Loop through each row

    for rows.Next() {

        // 3. Create a struct of passed mode interface{} type
        rowp := reflect.New(destv.Type().Elem())
        rowv := rowp.Elem()

        // 4. Scan the row results to a slice of interface{}
        // 5. Set the field values of struct created in step 3 using the slice in step 4
        //
        // Scan directly to the struct fields so the database
        // package handles the conversion from database
        // types to a Go types.
        //
        // The slice args is filled with pointers to struct fields.

        for i := 0; i < rowv.NumField(); i++ {
            args[i] = rowv.Field(i).Addr().Interface()
        }

        if err := rows.Scan(args...); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        // 6. Add the struct created in step 3 to slice created in step 1

        destv.Set(reflect.Append(destv, rowv))

    }
    return nil
}
```

Call it like this:

```
func (m *ContractModel) Documents(cid int) ([]*models.Document, error) {
    results, err := m.DB.Query(queries.DOCUMENTS, cid)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer results.Close()
    var documents []*models.Document
    err := RowsToStruct(results, &documents)
    return documents, err
}
```

Eliminate more boilerplate by moving the query to a helper function:

```
func QueryToStructs(dest interface{}, db *sql.DB, q string, args ...interface{}) error {
    rows, err := db.Query(q, args...)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    return RowsToStructs(rows, dest)
}
```

Call it like this:

```
func (m *ContractModel) Documents(cid int) ([]*models.Document, error) {
    var documents []*model.Document
    err := QueryToStructs(&documents, m.DB, queries.DOCUMENTS, cid)
    return documents, err
}
```

Comment: Few compile error fixes, **var args []interface{}** should be **args := make([]interface{}, rowv.NumField())** and **destv.Set(reflect.Append(destv, rowp))** should be **destv.Set(reflect.Append(destv, rowv))** I suggested an edit but it wasn't approved.

Comment: @S.Sandeep  I whipped up the code in the edit box here, but never ran it.    Thank you for reporting the errors. I edited the answer.

Comment: You saved me hundreds of hours. Many thanks!! This works flawlessly, as of Go `1.17.3`.

Answer (score 0):

My proposal to deal with "common code" is quite simple, relying mostly on the premise that retrieve/get operations most of the times are used to return those results to a web browser client. So, those results are, in turn, transformed into JSON leveraging the `json` package.

file: **db_common.go**

```
// Interface for things that performs an scan over a given row.
// Actually it is a common interface for https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Rows.Scan and https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Row.Scan
type RowScanner interface {
    Scan(dest ...interface{}) error
}

// Scans a single row from a given query
type RowScanFunc func(rows RowScanner) (interface{}, error)

// Scans multiples rows using a scanner function in order to build a new "scanable" struct
func ScanMultiples(rows *sql.Rows, rowScanFunc RowScanFunc) ([]interface{}, error) {
    scaneables := []interface{}{}
    for rows.Next() {
        scanable, err := rowScanFunc(rows)
        if scanable == nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        scaneables = append(scaneables, scanable)
    }
    err := rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return scaneables, nil
}
```

And then I used the above abstractions like this:

file: **dao/crud_operations.go**

```
// Type that models a row of a given db table
type TableRow struct {
    Id int
    Name string
    // more fields...
}

func GetAll() ([]interface{}, error) {
    rows, err := Db.Query(`
        SELECT id, name
        FROM a_table`
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    return ScanMultiples(rows, scanRow)
}

// Gets an specific legal entity by id
func GetById(id int) (interface{}, error) {
    row := Db.QueryRow(`
        SELECT id, name
        FROM a_table
        WHERE id = $1`, id)
    return scanRow(row)
}


// Scans a row interpreting it as 'TableRow' struct
func scanRow(rows RowScanner) (*TableRow, error) { // DO NOTE that implements the RowScanner interface!
    var tableRow TableRow

    err := rows.Scan(tableRow.Id,tableRow.Name)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &tableRow, nil
}
```

- The good thing is that you only must code a single function that scans a Row.
- Another good thing is that is not code tangled with external dependencies.
- Another good thing is that the code doesn't resort to `reflect` package or those complicated things.
- The bad thing is that you return interface{} and you may has to cast it to the original data type, having to write, 3 lines (in the worst case) for that.
- Again you don't have to worry if the resulting results are going to be Marshaled like `bytes, err := json.Marshal(results)`, because the `json` package receives an `interface{} (=any)` as parameter.

Answer (score -1):

*"... but reflect package cannot create a slice of struct from a passed interface{} type."* -- You looking for this?

```
func sliceFromElemValue(v interface{}) (interface{}) {
    rt := reflect.TypeOf(v)
    rs := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(rt), 0, 0)

    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ { // dummy loop
        rs = reflect.Append(rs, reflect.New(rt).Elem())
    }

    return rs.Interface()
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/o4AJ-f71egw

---

*"What I need to achieve is something like as follows"*

```
func RowsToStructs(rows *sql.Rows, model interface{}) ([]interface{}, error) { ...
```

Or are you looking for this?

```
func sliceFromElemValue(v interface{}) ([]interface{}) {
    rt := reflect.TypeOf(v)
    s := []interface{}{}

    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ { // dummy loop
        s = append(s, reflect.New(rt).Elem().Interface())
    }

    return s
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/i57Z8OO8n7G